# Populate listbox using single (delimited) field from Table (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

How to do this in VBA?
In table `Features` I have column `Colors`. Single field there has the following data: `black; blue; yellow` - delimited with `;`
On `Access` form I want to populate a listbox (`lstColors`) with data from that single field so that I get the list with:

```
black

blue

yellow
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What code do you have so far? This is a faily simple task if you can assign your colors field to a strColors variable. Then use Split function on the variable using comma delimiter. Then use loop to AddItem to you listbox. You can build your own code now with this information - then come back with any problems you've encountered

Answer (score 0):

Set the *RowSourceType* of the listbox to: *ValueList*

Set the *RowSource* to the value from your field *Colors* which is a list of values.